# How to keep two different versions of Ruby on the same machine without conflict?

Tags: ruby, windows

I have installed Ruby 2.0.0 and Ruby 1.9.3-p392. But lots of gems, like `nokogiri` and `selenium-webdriver`, are not compatible with 2.0, thus I am bound to keep 1.9.3 on my Windows machine. Now the problem is 2.0.0 get rides on 1.9.3. Thus I am not able to run the code which is using the aforementioned gems from my editor Sublime Text 2.

Thus any idea how to keep them both on the same machine without any conflict?

Comment: I've been wondering this too, and the only thing i could think of was a virtual machine. As a dev, you will probably get tired of ruining your development machine over and over. VMs are your best friend!

Comment: [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) should work, although it looks like it hasn't been updated in a while. Also, you need to have Ruby installed to use it.

Comment: @Hiroto I have given some sources as answers,very useful.you can check it out.

Comment: Nokogiri works fine with Ruby 2.0.

Comment: What does "2.0.0 get rides on 1.9.3" mean?

Comment: @theTinMan I tried Ruby2.0.0 with `nokogiri`, but I got error. Thus I revert back it to 1.9.3p397.

Comment: Then something is wrong on your system. I have v2.0 running on three different machines and Nokogiri works fine on all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got couple of sources to do so:

- [Ruby version manager](http://www.ruby-on-rails-outsourcing.com/articles/2010/07/28/ruby-version-manager-for-windows/)
- [Setting the default ruby with Pik](http://squarism.com/2011/01/18/setting-the-default-ruby-with-pik/)